# Duplicate lines and make them unique?

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression, csv, text

**I have the following structure of text lines:**

```
3923 001    L05 LV,L05 RM
3923 002    L12 RA,L12 LA
3923 003    I06 ALL
3923 004    G04 RV,Z09 ALL
```

**but i would need this:**

```
3923 001    L05 LV
3923 001    L05 RM
3923 002    L12 RA
3923 002    L12 LA
3923 003    I06 ALL
3923 004    G04 RV
3923 004    Z09 ALL
```

Is this possible with a regex ?

Basicly I need every line copyd the amount of times it contains a "," and then made unique starting from the 10nth character; if i could get the first part done, so just a copy of every line x the amount of comma's, i could clean the rest manually

Comment: You can't give assignments to ppl over here.So,what have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried using: find: , replace by;  ^.......... [] ; i'm a total noob at this; i'm trying to learn, sorry if i posted this wrong. :(

Comment: No worries....Just post it even if it is wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the format of your example this should work for any number of comma separated strings after the initial large space(if it's a tab just change the spaces in the second `s///` to `\t`

```
sed ':;h;s/,.*//;p;x;s/    [^,]*,/    /;t;d' file

3923 001    L05 LV
3923 001    L05 RM
3923 002    L12 RA
3923 002    L12 LA
3923 003    I06 ALL
3923 004    G04 RV
3923 004    Z09 ALL
```

If you want tabs then

> if you want to write the tab as \t, you can give it to Bash using $'' quotes: sed $':;h;s/,.*//;p;x;s/\t[^,]*,/ /;t;d'. Or just insert a literal tab (for bash, you need to type control-v to enter it literally). .
>
> — [Toby Speight](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216399/duplicate-lines-and-make-them-unique/216405#comment367256_216405)

Comment: Upvoted.Works with multiple "," too.

Comment: This will obviously be correct; but me being such a noob, i'm not getting it to work, the large space is a tab, so the code becomes ? sed ':;h;s/,.*//;p;x;s/\t[^,]*,/    /;t;d' file ?

Comment: @Randy - if you want to write the tab as `\t`, you can give it to Bash using `$''` quotes: `sed $':;h;s/,.*//;p;x;s/\t[^,]*,/ /;t;d'`.  Or just insert a literal tab (for bash, you need to type control-v to enter it literally).

Answer (score 3):

It is possible using sed. Pipe the input to the below.

```
| sed 's/\(^.\{12\}\)\([^,]\+\),\([^,]\+\)/\1\2\n\1\3/'
```

output

```
3923 001    L05 LV
3923 001    L05 RM
3923 002    L12 RA
3923 002    L12 LA
3923 003    I06 ALL
3923 004    G04 RV
3923 004    Z09 ALL
```

Here is the source to handle input with multiple ","

For original input without tab, use

```
| perl -ne '/,/ && do {chomp;s/^(.{12})(.+)/$1,$2/; @l = split(","); foreach $a (@l[1 .. $#l]) {print "$l[0]$a\n";};1;} || do {print;}'
```

If input has tab, use

```
| perl -ne '/,/ && do{chomp; s/^([^\t]+\t)(.+)/$1,$2/; @l = split(","); foreach $a (@l[1 .. $#l]) {print "$l[0]$a\n";};1;} || do {print;}'
```

Comment: Any reason for downvoting.

Comment: Downvoted...It adds extra blank line for every split

Comment: I added an extra new line based on previous input. It seems like the input is now modified.

Comment: Based on your current output, I figure you are trying pick the prefix upto 12th Character and not 10th. Can you clarify. I have already updated my solution.

Comment: The columns are not aligned

Comment: The columns are not aligned as the OP asked to pick the prefix upto 10th character of input. To fix , it should be upto 12th character. But that goes agains OP's requirement. I have already asked OP for clarification.

Comment: @soumen Not taking anyones side but to fair OP did post the expected output and it is formatted.

Comment: @User112638726, Sure. But the output conflicts a bit with the requirement. So, I have asked for clarification. If we replace '9' with '12', it will be formatted.

Comment: @Thushi and Archemar, can you reverse your downvote given that I have updated my post. Thanks.

Comment: What if he has multiple "," . Example: `3923 001 L05 LV,L05 RM,L09 AB`. In your case it will not split it out

Comment: @soumen: Reported one more use case

Comment: @Thushi, I agree my solution will not conform to various other use cases. But it works for the OP's requirement, ain't it. We are not here to provide everything but a nudge for the OP to help make further progress. Somehow, a downvote says current solution does not work for the given requirement.

Comment: But if you look into OP's requirement he says `Basicly I need every line copyd the amount of times it contains a "," and then made unique starting from the 10nth character; if i could get the first part done, so just a copy of every line x the amount of comma's, i could clean the rest manually`. That is the reason I informed you. Even I am not here to derive my own requirements. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution with `awk`:

```
awk -F" " '{ x = $3 " " $4 " " $5; split(x, a, ","); for (i in a) { print $1, $2 "\t" a[i]; } }' file
```

Output should be:

```
3923 001    L05 LV
3923 001    L05 RM
3923 002    L12 RA
3923 002    L12 LA
3923 003    I06 ALL 
3923 004    G04 RV
3923 004    Z09 ALL
```

And if your input contains multiple `,` as in comments: `3923 001 L05 LV,L05 RM,L09 AB` you can try this:

```
awk -F" " '{ x = $3; for (i = 4; i <= NF; i++) { x = x " " $i; } split(x, a, ","); for (i in a) { print $1, $2 "\t" a[i]; } }' file
```

Comment: Missing the - from the F flag.

Comment: @User112638726, sorry, thanks, I'll edit it.

Comment: Downvoting....What if he has multiple "," . Example: `3923 001    L05 LV,L05 RM,L09 AB`. In your case it will cut the AB

Comment: @taliezin: Works!!!

Answer (score 1):

Simplyfied variant of [User112638726 answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216405/89144)

```
sed ':1;s/\(\(.*\s\s\+\)[^,]\+\),/\1\n\2/;t1'
sed -r ':1;s/((.+\s\s+)[^,]+),/\1\n\2/;t1'
```

will choice repeated part as «any symbols before 2(or more) spaces».

Then you can pipe output through

```
uniq -s 10
```

Comment: If you are only using a single t/b, you don't need to  assign it a name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` and set the field separator to either spaces or comma. Then, loop in blocks of 2, printing the first and second fields together with blocks of two:

```
$ awk -v FS='(\\s+|,)' '{for (i=3; i<=NF; i+=2) print $1, $2, $i, $(i+1)}' file
3923 001 L05 LV
3923 001 L05 RM
3923 002 L12 RA
3923 002 L12 LA
3923 003 I06 ALL
3923 004 G04 RV
3923 004 Z09 ALL
```